# What did most recent update do?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update

I have a Lumia 950 XL (UK version, if that matters) and, this morning, it performed a system update. Anyone know what that might have contained or can point me to where I can find out?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is [the link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429/windows-10-update-kb4013429) you're looking for:

It says, more or less, that no new features were introduced in that update.